# variable in iframe with zk

Tags: iframe, data-binding, zk, zk-grid

i have a for each in my zk page, and in the each i am creating a column, and in my column i need add a iframe, and to each frame i need pass as variable the label of the column.

I have something like:

```
<zk>
          <window title="Dynamic Columns" border="normal" width="1824px" apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer" viewModel="@id('vm') @init('pkg$.DynamicColumnModel')">
<grid >

               <columns>
                  <column forEach="${vm.columnList}" label="${each}">

              <iframe 
        src="test.zul" />
                </column>
              </columns>
     </grid>
   </window>
</zk>
```

But i have an error when i include the page, and my first problem is that i do not know how can i pass a variable to each iframe.

And my java is something like:

```
public class DynamicColumnModel {

private List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
 private String texto="123";

@Init
public void init(){

    columnList.add("Dynamic Col A");
    columnList.add("Dynamic Col B");
    columnList.add("Dynamic Col C");
    columnList.add("Dynamic Col D");
}

public List<String> getColumnList() {
    return columnList;
}
public void setColumnList(List<String> columnList) {
    this.columnList = columnList;
}

 public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}
public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
}


@Command
   public void mensaje(){

  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think rather than calling Irame from here you can create from Java class and pass the value

Comment: But how can i pass from Java, or how can i create an i frame from java?

Comment: You have to use Wiring of ID(ZUL COmponent ID) for that @Wire in ViewModel

Comment: please, do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `each` is a `String`, which it appears to be as you set it as the column label, just go ahead and pass it as a URL parameter to the `iframe`.

```
    <window apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
            viewModel="@id('vm') @init('pkg$.DynamicColumnModel')">
        <grid >
            <columns>
                <column forEach="${vm.columnList}" label="${each}">
                    <iframe src="test.zul?myValue=${each}" />
                </column>
            </columns>
        </grid>
   </window>
```

Note that when you are using an `iframe` component, you are stepping outside ZK. True, the `iframe` itself points to a ZK page, but it's a not within the same ZK environment. The `iframe` could just as easily include `www.google.com` and so there is no specific ZK support for passing values to ZK pages included in this manner.

If you're only including ZK pages and want to pass information to these pages more fluidly, you'll want to use ZK's [`include`](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Include) tag. Have a look at the documentation on [how to pass values to included ZK pages](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Include#Pass_Values_to_the_Included_Page).

**Edit**
If going the `iframe` route, you can access URL parameter values from `test.zul` using ZK's [`Execution`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Execution.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) class:

```
Execution execution = Executions.getCurrent();
execution.getParameter("myValue");
```

Comment: And how can receive the variable in my iframe?

Comment: Because i need pass the variable that i receive in my model to do a query in DAO to show in my page that i include or call with the frame